# How to update different value in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have one problem which I don't know how to resloved.

I want update MySQL with different value for all "ID" which I have in MySQL.

I use PHP for this and this is my code:

```
//First ID check 

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subscription_end, today_date FROM users_manager WHERE id=62");

while($date = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $date['subscription_end'];
  $date['today_date'];

  if ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) {
    $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='of' WHERE id=62";
  } else {
    $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='on' WHERE id=62";
  }
}

//Second ID check
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subscription_end, today_date FROM users_manager WHERE id=50");

while($date = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  $date['subscription_end'];
  $date['today_date'];

  if ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) {
    $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='off' WHERE id=50";
  } else {
    $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='on' WHERE id=50";
  }
}
```

When I add new user and that user have new ID example 55 then I must again put one line of code for check new user.

Can you tell me how I can check all of this and new and old users all the time?

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more slick way of doing this using straight SQL, but from a PHP perspective...

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM  users_manager");
while($id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subscription_end, today_date FROM users_manager WHERE id=".$id['id']);
    while($date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        if ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) {
            $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='off' WHERE id=".$id['id'];
        } else {
            $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='on' WHERE id=".$id['id'];
        }
    $result3 = mysqli_query($conn, $update);
    mysqli_free_result($result2);
    mysqli_free_result($result3);
}
```

**Best Practice:** We strongly recommend you use PDO and bind your parameters (e.g., `bindParam()` to protect yourself against SQL injection.  An excellent discussion of the problems with examples of the solution are found [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).  My answer has not implemented this so you can see the solution in the context of your original question.

Comment: Hi JBH .. this is good .. but I don't undesrtand PDO ..
can you just explain me this .$id[0]; part
THX

Comment: There's no PDO in my example.  And I apologize, I made a mistake.  It should not be `$id[0]`, it should be `$id['id']`.  I'll update the answer.  $id is holding the SQL row for each ID found in the database.  The variable `$id['id']` access that ID number.  This allows you to process the the updates for each ID without having to know what they are.

Comment: Friend this is work now and I edit small part
while($date = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
        if ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) {
            $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='off' WHERE id=".$id['id'];
        } else {
            $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='on' WHERE id=".$id['id'];


"$result2" on second while loop

Comment: :-)  Right you are!  I've updated the answer.  Good Luck!

Comment: Thx my dear friend a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Everything is documented .. If you diden't get anything ask me.

```
/**
 * UserId:  This variable holds the userId,
 *          You have to bring it from database and referenced to this variable.
*/
$userId = 10;
// This variable represents the status column in the 'user_manager' Table.
$status = null;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subscription_end, today_date FROM 
users_manager WHERE id={$userId}");

while($date = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $date['subscription_end'];
    $date['today_date'];

    $status = ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) ? 'off' : 'on';

    $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status={$status} WHERE id={$userId}";

}
```

Comment: Hi S3FaQ El ... This is for manual put value in variable, but I need automatical for check all ID in MySQL.

In MySQL I have table called "users_manager" in that table I have 3 columns named: subscription_end, today_date, status .. I need only make check for all user in MySQL ...

If I enter new user in MySQL that user have its ID then for ecah user I must repeat this line of code.

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT subscription_end, today_date 
     FROM users_manager WHERE id=62");

     while($date = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
     $date['subscription_end'];
     $date['today_date'];

     if ($date['subscription_end'] <= $date['today_date']) {
     $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='0' WHERE id=62";
     } else {
     $update = "UPDATE users_manager SET status='1' WHERE id=62";
     }

Comment: Yes that exactly what i wrote there, pleae re-read the comment .. anyway, i sat a vatiable called $userId that variable must hold the userid automaticaly from the database you can get it by a simple query statement

Comment: Yes I see that .. but what if I want check all ID in Database and all of that ID I want UPDATE different value on or off.

Sorry friend but I don't understand what you mean exactly 

I can get ID from MySQL over 

this comand 

$getid = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id,  FROM users_manager");

while($id = mysqli_fetch_array($getid))
{
$id['id'];

This will select all ID for MySQL.